# Do Linux Live CDs properly shut down USB devices when you power off?

Tags: linux, usb, shutdown

I’ve been using a Live CD with a USB drive that has my [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org) database on it, when I shut the system down I noticed that the USB light doesn’t shut off before it asks me to remove the media (CD) and then hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to shut down. On my regular installation when I shut down the light turns off before it hits the shut down screen seconds before powering off.

Comment: Why not inspect the shutdown scripts of each installation (e.g. `/etc/rc.shutdown`)?

Answer (score 1):

Any livecd worth using is going to try and safely unmount filesystems during a proper shutdown.  Properly unmounting the filesystem is what you really should be concerned about.  A correctly unmounted filesystem should mean that all data has been properly stored.

But since there is such a wide variety of livecds there is simply no way to give a single authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well a Live USB does the same thing as your HDD installed OS. It holds on to certain files and shutdown when its done. Since the Live USB stores all OS based information on the RAM and just accesses the USB for read functionality, there would be no harm. Even while shutting down, there would be no effect to the USB. You could also treat those sectors a one-time write DVD.